# Porque é que em ptPT não se usa o gerúndio?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, gerúndios

Vou frequentemente a Portugal e nunca ouvi um nativo usar o gerúndio como é usado no Brasil.  Em ptPT usa-se "estar a + infinitivo".

Enquanto no Brasil dizemos "ela está cantando" e "ele está discutindo", nossos amigos Lusitanos dizem "ela está a cantar" e "ele está a discutir".  Como foi que se deu essa diferença entre o falar dos dois povos?  Já existiu o gerúndio em ptPT e foi aos poucos substituído por "estar a + infinitivo?  Será que ainda é usado e "calhou" que eu nunca percebi?

Why is it that the Portuguese never use the gerund? I often visit Portugal, where I have family, and I never heard a Portuguese use the gerund the way it is used in Brazil.  Brazilians say "she is singing" whereas the Portuguese use a "estar a + infinitive" construction to mean the same.  Have the Portuguese ever used the gerund or can it be that they still use it but I never heard?

Comment: É sempre difícil determinar uma explicação exata que explique por que isto ou aquilo aconteceu na língua. É melhor perguntar quando e como.

Comment: @tchrist "que explique" is a pleonasm and, imho, would be better omitted.

Comment: Pleonasmo é "explicação que explique", toda a expressão, não apenas o "que explique". Só pra deixar claro =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bom, não é verdade que em Portugal não se usa o gerúndio. A construção "estar + <gerúndio>" é um caso particular -- e mesmo essa construção é ainda usada Portugal, principalmente no Alentejo e no Algarve. Traduzindo [deste artigo](http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/Archive/zY1ZjNlM/tmoia_eviotti_JPL2004.pdf):

> Em linhas gerais, podemos dizer que o uso do gerúndio no português europeu é bastante semelhante ao do português brasileiro. E de facto, esta forma verbal ocorre nos mesmos (cinco) tipos principais de contexto sintático e associa-se aos mesmos valores semânticos interproposicionais -- por exemplo, temporal, elaborativo, causal, instrumental, condicional e contrastivo -- quando usado como advérbio.

mas

> Mais notável é a diferença entre EP e BP que consiste no facto de que em (pelo menos algumas variedades de) EP, o gerúndio tende a cair em desuso após alguns verbos auxiliares aspetuais, como *estar* ou *andar*, ou após algumas orações adverbiais envolvendo sobreposição temporal de atividades, por exemplo. Uma vez que estas construções são muito comuns, o impacto deste tipo de variação entre EP e BP torna-se bastante percetível.

Já [estoutro artigo](https://web.archive.org/web/20200524232319/http://www.gel.hospedagemdesites.ws/estudoslinguisticos/edicoesanteriores/4publica-estudos-2006/sistema06/356.pdf) explora o período em que o uso daquilo a que chama "infinitivo gerundivo" começou a ganhar terreno e conclui que se trata de um fenómeno que se iniciou no final do século XIX:

[image]

Quanto ao porquê, este último artigo sugere uma possível via para a gramaticalização do infinitivo gerundivo -- construções ambíguas em que *a + infinito* pode significar o mesmo que o gerúndio ou onde podemos atribuir um significado não vazio à preposição *a*:

> Dados ambíguos –- Esses reúnem os casos em que, na alternância gerúndio x
>   infinitivo gerundivo há possibilidade de uma dupla leitura para tal “a” (1- vazio de sentido; ou também 2- com o sentido de preposição “para”, “junto a”, etc). A hipótese para esse grupo de fatores é de que o avanço do infinitivo gerundivo nos casos ambíguos pode estar a apontar para uma possível gramaticalização da preposição “a” como um “prefixo aspectual”.
>
> Exemplo de cambialidade ambígua entre infinitivo gerundivo e gerúndio:
>   *“(...) eu já não posso mais, porque estou a fazer uma coisa, mesmo que não tenha importância, levo três quartos de hora **a fazer** uma coisa que eu fazia em cinco minutos”*. (Oc-P-70-1M-002)
>   Aqui, poderíamos novamente ter uma dupla interpretação: “levo três quartos de hora **fazendo** uma coisa” ou “levo três quartos de hora **para fazer** uma coisa”.

Comment: Adicionalmente: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/696/261

Comment: Esta questão da formação do formação do infinitivo gerundivo merecia ser mais aprofundada. Tou a pensar que *estar à espera* e *estar a esperar* são sinónimos, tal como *estar a escutar/à escuta, andar a caçar/à caça*.

Comment: Será porventura também preguiça ou simplificação da língua? Dizer apenas o infinitivo seguido da preposição `a`, é mais fácil de memorizar e proferir, que o gerúndio do verbo, ou seja, extrair a raiz do verbo e adicionar `endo` ou `indo`. Será?

Comment: O link para "estoutro artigo" apodreceu, você consegue achar um que funcione, Artefacto, ou ao menos a citação completa (título, autores, etc.) do artigo?

Answer (score 3):

Usa-se o gerundio sim, mas menos frequente que no Brasil. Ex.:

- *sendo assim*
- *indo eu*
- *ir falando*

etc.

Answer (score 1):

O português europeu até o século XIX utilizava-se do gerundio. Estar + a é uma evolução; portanto, é recente. Haja vista que o sul de Portugal continou com a forma antiga. O Brasil sempre usou a forma antiga. Artigo publicado na Revista Argumento, Ano 18, Número 27 (2017), cujo título é: PERÍFRASES COM GERÚNDIO E COM INFINITIVO PREPOSICIONADO: REVISITANDO UM DOS ASPECTOS DA HIPÓTESE CONSERVADORA DA FORMAÇÃO DO PB1 Lelia Alves de Oliveira

Comment: Olá @A.M., tens referência sobre isso para dar base a tua resposta?

Comment: Sim. Artigo publicado na Revista Argumento, Ano 18, Número 27 (2017), cujo título é: 
 PERÍFRASES COM GERÚNDIO E COM INFINITIVO PREPOSICIONADO: REVISITANDO UM DOS ASPECTOS DA HIPÓTESE CONSERVADORA DA FORMAÇÃO DO PB1
Lelia Alves de Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

Para mim, até pela época em que foi aparecendo, é uma influência do Francês, que era muito forte (pode mesmo dizer-se quase hegemónica) nas classes instruídas, sobretudo a partir de meados do século XIX. No Brasil essa influência podia também fazer-se sentir, mas talvez menos intensamente.

Exemplos (ilustrativos da tendência do Francês, não pretendem ser reconstituições):

- não tem que ficar esperando (vous n'avez pas à attendre)
- se pôs chorando (il est resté là à pleurer)
- estou lendo (Je suis en train de lire)
- o que resta para ir fazendo (ce qu'il reste à faire)