# Colocação pronominal no português europeu: “que ela te ajuda” vs. “que ela ajuda-te”

Tags: português-europeu, sintaxe, colocação-pronominal

É sabido que o português europeu tem uma preferência pela ênclise em frases “simples” como *ela ajuda-me*, mas prefere a próclise quando no início da frase há uma de várias palavrinhas a que vi algures chamarem “palavras atrativas”: *ela não me ajuda, ela também me ajuda,* etc. Na minha resposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-pronominal?rq=1) eu listei *que* como uma dessas palavrinhas que pede a próclise. E parece que tanto faz *que* ser pronome relativo (a) ou conjunção (b):

> (a) Isso é um assunto em *que ela **te** ajuda*
>
> (b) O João diz *que ela **te** ajuda*

Mas eu e, creio, a maioria do pessoal em Portugal dizemos:

> (c) Fala com a Joana, *que ela ajuda-**te***

Que é que se passa aqui? As orações em itálico começam todas com *(em) que* e empregam as mesmas palavras na mesma ordem, com a exceção de o *te* saltar de lugar. Há alguma explicação para este salto?

Eu sei que a conjunção *que* tem significados diferentes em (b) e (c). Mas isso é relevante?

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013) diz que ao longo da história a próclise sempre foi obrigatória em orações subordinadas (tomo I, p. 36). Mas (c) é oração subordinada, ou não?

Eu sei que a conjunção *que* tem significados diferentes em (b) e (c). Mas isso é relevante? A única outra diferença que eu vejo é que em (c) o *que* é precedido de vírgula, ou uma ligeira pausa na fala. Mas essa pausa também acontece em

> (d) Querido filho, *que Deus **te** ajude*

e lá temos de novo a próclise!

Comment: "Nesta resposta"? Qual? Faltou-te um link.

Comment: Olha que (d) e (c) não são semelhantes, Jacinto. Podemos dizer só "que deus te ajude", mas não se diria só "que ela ajuda-te" - e talvez essa seja a razão porque os *tes* vão em sítios diferentes.

Comment: (c) é coordenada explicativa, daí a ênclise.

Comment: @ANeves, são semelhantes no serem precedidas de pausa. Sim, no caso da (d) a pausa pode ser muito longa, ou não haver sequer nada antes.

Comment: @Artefacto, tipo "fala com a Joana, e ela ajuda-te"? Estava a ver a segunda oração mais como consequência da primeira. Isso é um padrão, a ênclise na coordenadas explicativas?

Comment: julgo que são resquícios dos problemas das orações auxiliares, que no Latim (tal como em Alemão), colocam sempre o verbo no final. Assim, neste sentido, parece-me que semanticamente `que ela te ajuda` seria mais correto. Mas é apenas uma presunção.

Comment: Não ponho resposta por não saber com certeza, mas posso comentar que uma pausa ou uma grande distância da palavra pode favorecer ênclise no asturiano quando estritamente esperaríamos próclise.

Comment: @guifa, uma grande distância da palavra, com coisas intercaladas, também pode acontecer no português. Mas é uma coisa que nós corrigiríamos numa segunda leitura. Neste caso eu recuso-me a mudar a posição do clítico.

Comment: Parece-me um caso de ênclise. Talvez o "que" possa dar a impressão que deva ser próclise por ser comum em construções que requerem próclise. Por exemplo «eu acho que ela só te ajuda porque é muito tua amiga».

Comment: @Rui, que requer ênclise eu não tenho dúvida. "Fala com a Joana, que ela ajuda-te", é como eu falo normalmente. Mas, "come a sopa, que te faz bem". A questão é porquê?