# Por que “senhora”, no Brasil, é “senhóra”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia

A maioria das palavras terminadas em -ôr terminam em -ôra no feminino, mas a palavra *senhora* é uma exceção, pois, tem o aberto. Em Portugal, porém, *senhora* fala-se como *senhôra*, então não me parece ser pela etimologia.

Então por que *senhora* fala-se como *senhóra* no Brasil e não *senhôra*?

Comment: Realmente, palavras como cantora, locutora, digitadora, diretora, trituradora, e dezenas de femininos terminados em "ora", seguem a pronuncia de seus respectivos masculinos, com um "o" fechado.  Esperar-se-ia então que "senhora"  seguisse a regra.  Mas não segue.  Desconheço o porquê.

Comment: @Centaurus, realmente é curioso. Pela resposta do Stafusa, já seguiu essa regra, e em Portugal ainda segue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pronúncia aberta parece ter se tornado dominante no Brasil (relativamente) recentemente. O Houaiss, por exemplo, observa:

> o timbre da vogal tônica de *senhora*, fechado, ainda perdura no Brasil entre idosos ou entre os pretensamente bem-falantes

E um [relato](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-senhora-ou-a-senhora/1709) no Ciberdúvidas sugere que nos anos 1990 ainda havia quem considerasse não culta a pronúncia aberta.

Pessoalmente, eu sequer conhecia a pronúncia com "o" fechado e, na minha opinião, o "o" aberto é uma pronúncia mais natural em pt-BR, em linha com "melhora" e "penhora" — embora isso obviamente varie com os dialetos locais. Então talvez este seja um ajuste orgânico, sem origem bem definida.

Seria muito interessante conhecer registros de como essa alteração se passou. Na falta deles, vale notar que no Ciberdúvidas se menciona que também em Açores o "o" em "senhora" é aberto, e a influência açoriana sobre o pt-BR, especialmente no sul do país, é bem documentada (e.g., [1](https://www.brapci.inf.br/index.php/res/v/13151), [2](https://doi.org/10.4000/geolinguistique.1633), [3](https://anpuh.org.br/uploads/anais-simposios/pdf/2018-12/1543978800_584cdb705ef2df8e245be2c08d0b4979.pdf)), então esta talvez seja uma possível origem. Também se poderia especular sobre algum dialeto nordestino ou até o italiano *signora*, mas não encontrei evidência alguma em favor dessas hipóteses.

Comment: Muito interessante. Vê lá tu que eu nem nunca me tinha apercebido desse *Senh**òr**a*. Agora, e sou é cada vez mais cético acerca de influências externas na pronúncia. Fiquei muito persuadido por [esta resposta do Luís Henrique](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/que-mudan%c3%a7as-a-imigra%c3%a7%c3%a3o-italiana-determinou-no-modo-de-falar-dos-paulistas/5093#5093), onde ele conclui que as línguas são muito recetivas a vocabulário estrangeiro, mas muito resistentes a outras influências, como na pronúncia. Essa pronúncia de *senhora* é exclusiva da área de imigração açoriana?

Comment: Aliás, uma resposta recente tua aponta para aí também. Embora popularmente se atribua as diferenças entre a pronúncia brasileira e a europeia à influência no português brasileiro de línguas que não o português, a tua conclusão é que provavelmente é a pronúncia brasileira que se manteve mais próxima do português clássico, e portanto que foi o português europeu que mudou mais, sem nenhuma influência externa para explicar  essa mudança.

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo. Foi o que quis dizer com "ajuste orgânico". Se houver uma origem geográfica definida, creio que a nordestina seja mais provável que uma açoriana (como de Florianópolis), mas como o dialeto açoriano é mencionado mais de uma vez nesse contexto, achei por bem incluir. E a resposta do Luís Henrique de fato é excelente, outra língua influenciar a pronúncia ou a gramática parece mesmo ser muito difícil.

Comment: Pois, o que é curioso é ser só em *senhora*. Ou não é? Aliás, "mais natural em pt-BR, em linha com 'melhora' e 'penhora' "... não seria mais natural ser em linha com o **ô** fechado de *cantora, locutora, digitadora, diretora*, etc? (comentário do Centaurus acima.)

Comment: @Jacinto Me parece mais fácil a pronúncia aberta em (nh/lh)ora, não em *ora (mas admito que não conheço muitos exemplos, pode ser um efeito de amostragem).

Comment: Stafusa, a palavra senhora é bem antiga, o Houaiss a data século III, e várias palavras terminadas -or(a), como melhor, pior, agora, porém não ora nem hora, tinham o fechado. Então será que senhora acabou passando por essa transformação de algum modo? Se eu não me engano, uma das grandes características do galego-português era que palavras terminadas em -or eram invariáveis em gênero. Talvez as datas façam sentido. Ademais, conseqüentemente, palavras terminadas em -ora não abundavam, e as que existiam tinham o aberto, como *móra*, *fóra*. Então, talvez seja por influência dessas.

Comment: Sim, @Schilive, me lembro de ter visto em algum lugar que se usava "senhor" para mulheres também. Sobre como essa mudança de pronúncia se passou, infelizmente só posso especular.