# “O século está a expirar”—estar + a + infinitivo no Brasil

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem-histórica, sintaxe, gerúndios

Uma das diferenças mais marcantes entre o português do Brasil e de Portugal atuais é o uso em Portugal de *a* + infinitivo em vez do gerúndio do Brasil:

> *Ele está a dormir* versus *ele está dormindo*.
>
> *Andaram a espalhar boatos* versus *andaram espalhando boatos*

Foi então com alguma surpresa que me deparei com a “construção lusitana” no [*Dom Casmurro* (1899) de Machado de Assis](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv00180a.pdf); alguns exemplos (ênfase minha)

> Não me recorda um só dos argumentos que empreguei, nem talvez interesse conhecê-los, agora que o século **está a expirar**;
>
> […] mas Capitu, antes que o pai acabasse de entrar, fez um gesto inesperado, pousou a boca na minha boca, e deu de vontade o que **estava a recusar** à força
>
> Como **estivesse a espiar** os peraltas da vizinhança, vi um destes que conversava com a minha amiga ao pé da janela.
>
> Chegara ao último degrau, e uma idéia me entrou no cérebro, como se **estivesse a esperar** por mim, entre as grades da cancela.
>
> Os ratos **continuam a infestar-me** a casa, que é o diabo

Poder-se-ia pensar que isto fosse coisa do português antigo, que entretanto tivesse desaparecido no Brasil. Mas a resposta do Artefacto a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/874/porque-%C3%A9-que-em-ptpt-n%C3%A3o-se-usa-o-ger%C3%BAndio) sugere que o *estar* + gerúndio é a construção mais antiga no português, e que *estar* + a + infinitivo, mesmo em Portugal, só em finais do século XIX começou a dar os primeiros passos. As minhas leituras de autores portugueses do século XIX dão-me também essa impressão. Podemos também excluir outra explicação: aqueles exemplos vêm todos da voz, ou pena, do Bento, brasileiro filho de brasileiros; não é portanto um português acabado de chegar ao Brasil.

Então a pergunta é: quão significativo foi o uso do *a* + infinitivo em vez do gerúndio no Brasil? Quando é que começou e até quando durou? Será que o [Machado de Assis (1839-1908, Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machado_de_Assis) foi uma exceção? Se ele não foi exceção, põe-se uma outra questão bem mais complicada (e que se ninguém conseguir responder, eu já fico satisfeito com a resposta à questão anterior), que é: donde é que isto veio? Será que o *a* + infinitivo já era usado em vez do gerúndio há mais tempo, em Portugal e no Brasil, do que o artigo citado pelo Artefacto sugere? Se não, como é que surge em Portugal e no Brasil mais ou menos na mesma altura?

Comment: 1. «aqueles exemplos **vêm**»; 2. «com a resposta **à** questão anterior»; e 3. a última frase devia acabar em ponto de interrogação, e não em ponto final.

Comment: Minha experiência completamente anedotal e parcial de um brasileiro ainda no princípio da vida: a formação com o gerúndio é recente o suficiente para que o termo _[gerundismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundismo)_ exista. Em especial, nos anos 90 e 2000, com a popularização dos serviços de _call center_, o assunto foi discutido o suficiente para tornar-se parte da [cultura popular brasileira](https://faciletrando.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/gerundismo.jpeg).

Comment: @RamonMelo O estar/andar + gerúndio já existia, em Portugal e no Brasil, nos séculos XVIII e XIX. Vê a resposta do Artefacto na pergunta linkada. Talvez *gerundismo* se refira a outros usos do gerúndio (não estar/andar +...). Pelo contrário, pela informação que tenho, *estar/andar* + *a* + infinitivo, é que é relativamente recente, século e picos...

Comment: Sem dúvida já existia. Só quis demonstrar que a popularização deste uso é suficientemente recente para causar o estranhamento. O termo _gerundismo_, infelizmente, não tem nenhuma definição mais elaborada que "o uso excessivo do gerúndio" (que eu conheça, ao menos). O próprio conceito de "excessivo", neste caso, é mais individual do que objetivo.

Comment: @Ramon Mas no confronto *estar + gerúndio* versus *estar + a + infinitivo* (e é só disso que a pergunta trata), ao que parece o gerúndio foi a única forma usada no português antigo.

Comment: Mas o _gerundismo_ costuma se aplicar a esta construção "estar + gerúndio" mesmo, dá uma olhada na charge para ver a ênfase que o artista dá. Estou tentando dizer que o uso da construção "estar + a + infinitivo", em algum momento da história, foi comum no Brasil, o que parece me sugerir (mas posso estar errado) que Machado de Assis não foi uma exceção. Meu conhecimento sobre o assunto termina por aí, infelizmente.

Comment: Jacinto,  não duvido que alguns brasileiros ainda usem o "estar + infinitivo" em algumas situações formais e sejam perfeitamente compreendidos por todos. Eu mesmo poderia talvez algum dia ter dito alguma coisa do tipo "vocês estão a brincar com coisa séria"  e nem tenha percebido.  Eu acredito que o pt-BR foi se distanciando do pt-PT na primeira metade do século XX e que na época de Machado nossos falares ainda eram bem semelhantes.

Comment: @Centaurus Mas neste aspeto particular eu não esperaria uma semelhança entre Portugal e Brasil no tempo do Machado de Assis. Uma coisa é uma construção que já vem do sXV ou XVI e que naturalmente existia nos dois países. Mas segundo a resposta do Artefacto, o *a* + infinitivo no lugar de gerúndio é uma coisa recente. Portanto é curioso que aparecesse ao mesmo tempo nos dois países.

Comment: @Ramon Descobri [isto na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundismo): o gerundismo não é a substituição de *a* + infinitivo por gerúndio, mas a substituição do presente, futuro simples, etc. pelo gerúndio, e.g. *amanhã estou indo à praia* em vez de *amanhã vou à praia* e coisas assim.

Comment: @Jacinto  O "gerundismo", considerado uma praga pela gramática prescritiva, é o "estarei lhe telefonando mais tarde", "estarei dando o seu recado", "estaremos encontrando você amanhã".

Comment: @Jacinto    Não deve ter aparecido ao mesmo tempo nos dois países. Alguém adotou o falar de alguém.  Acredito que no século XIX a elite brasileira ainda adotasse com muita facilidade os modismos portugueses.

Comment: @Centaurus Não sei se *a* + infinitivo era modismo nessa altura em Portugal. O gerúndio é que eu encontro na literatura dessa época.

Comment: @Jacinto   Não estou **a afirmar** nada.  São suposições.

Comment: Tem muito "gerundismo" em português que vem do inglês "ao viés" da tradução  mal feita. O pessoal não sabe traduzir e sai cada uma......Mas, me digan, os portugueses não sempre usaram "estar + a + infinitivo"? Pessoalmente, na minha experiência em Portugal, só tenho ouvido na conversa cotidiana, essa forma. Nunca ouvi um português/guesa dizer: "O qué que estas fazendo?"

Comment: @Lambie, em autores portugueses do sXIX o que encontras mais frequentemente é "estar + gerúndio", como falam os brasileiros hoje em dia. Essa construção sobreviveu até há pouco tempo (talvez sobreviva ainda) no Alentejo, Algarve e Açores. Se "estar + a + infinitivo" também já vem do português antigo é que eu não sei. No Eça de Queiroz, sXIX, já se encontra.

Comment: Obrigada pela informação.

Comment: @Lambie, olha, ainda anteontem ouvi um português a usar o "estar + gerúndio"--"Está chovendo". Pelo sotaque, era alentejano, do sul, onde esta construção sobreviveu até mais recentemente. Agora não sei se ele fala habitualmente assim ou se estava na brincadeira a recuperar modos de falar que ele ouviu aos pais ou avós dele.

Comment: @Jacinto Então, é mais provável ouvir o estar + gérundio em Portugal do que ouvir à + verbo no infinitivo no Brasil. E nem um ou o outro é o que se qualificaria de gerundismo. (Tenho certeza que não estamos à discutir os phrasal verbs. [humor])

Answer (score 1):

Das passagens que li do [*Dicionário de Machado de Assis: língua, estilo, temas*, de Castelar de Carvalho](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), entendo que, essencialmente, era parte do estilo de Machado de Assis. Destaco dois aspectos da questão e depois arrisco umas respostas:

1. **Influência portuguesa** - Com mãe e esposa portuguesas e importantes [amizades](https://pontesdevista.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/machado-de-assis-e-os-portugueses/) com autores portugueses, é [sabido](http://ensina.rtp.pt/artigo/a-ligacao-de-machado-de-assis-a-literatura-portuguesa/) que a afinidade do autor com o português europeu ia além do conhecimento dos clássicos. E, com a identidade linguística nacional ainda em (polêmica) formação, na época "o patrulhamento gramatical era impiedoso" [[ibid., pg. 44](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=coloquialismos&f=false)] e o português literário brasileiro era por vezes mais próximo do europeu que da linguagem coloquial brasileira, como se observa, e.g., na sua colocação pronominal [[ibid., pg. 38](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA39&dq=%22machado%20de%20assis%22%20%22portugu%C3%AAs%20europeu%22&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=%22coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20pronominal%22&f=false)]:

   > Machado colocava os pronomes à moda lusitana, como, de resto, todos os escritores do seu tempo. [...] Encontram-se, entretanto, alguns poucos exemplos da próclise à brasileira [...], em construções que contrariam os padrões gramaticais da época.
2. **Recurso semântico** - No entanto, de Carvalho vê [[ibid., pg. 67](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA39&ots=cUBfuzbaJS&pg=PA67#v=snippet&q=%22ficar%20%20%20infinitivo%22&f=false)] significados distintos nas construções com o infinitivo e o gerúndio, quando usadas por personagens brasileiras: por exemplo, embora ambas denotem ações progressivas ou durativas, nas construções "*andar + ger./inf.*", a com infinitivo denotaria intensidade ou reiteração. Ele exemplifica com esse diálogo de *Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas*:

   > — **Anda visitando** os defuntos? disse-lhe eu. — Ora, defuntos! respondeu Virgília com um muxoxo. E depois de me apertar as mãos: — **Ando a ver** se ponho os vadios para a rua.

Assim, sugiro algumas respostas:

> quão significativo foi o uso do a + infinitivo em vez do gerúndio no Brasil? Quando é que começou e até quando durou?

Pelo menos até o século XIX a influência da literatura e até da crítica literária portuguesa sobre os autores brasileiros parece considerável. Isto, talvez juntamente com a migração portuguesa para o Brasil ([significativa](https://brasil500anos.ibge.gov.br/territorio-brasileiro-e-povoamento/portugueses.html) no século XVIII), talvez explique porque a construção com o infinitivo surgiu "em Portugal e no Brasil mais ou menos na mesma altura". E seria então de se esperar que, com o declínio dessa influência, a literatura tenha passado a refletir a preferência popular pelo gerúndio. Esse argumento prevê uma vida curta no Brasil para a construção com o infinitivo, dificilmente se prolongando além do início do século XX. Mas isso é pouco mais que achismo - uma pesquisa nos corpus, por exemplo, seria necessária para dar mais fundamento à estimativa.

> Será que o Machado de Assis (1839-1908, Wikipédia) foi uma exceção?

Provavelmente sim. Machado é "considerado um escritor clássico em termos de linguagem" [[ibid., pg. 44](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=coloquialismos&f=false)], o que, juntamente com a influência de família e amigos portugueses, torna bem possível que o português europeu tenha influenciado mais ele que outros autores contemporâneos. Por exemplo, discorrendo sobre o uso de "*estar, andar, ir, ficar + infinitivo*", de Carvalho escreve [[ibid., pg. 67](https://books.google.de/books?id=0yiODwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA39&ots=cUBfuzbaJS&pg=PA67#v=snippet&q=%22ficar%20%20%20infinitivo%22&f=false)] que "Machado demonstra certa preferência por esta construção, à moda lusitana.", o que sugere ser esta uma idiossincrasia sua e não uma escolha difundida entre os autores brasileiros da época.

Comment: Eu li algures que ele seguiu muito os clássicos portugueses, nomeadamente o Garrett (não sei quem seriam os outros clássicos ao tempo Machado; mesmo o Garrett nasceu uns meros 40 anos antes dele); mas não me lembro se o Garrett usava *estar a* + infinitivo.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, vi isso agora também. Incluí na resposta uma menção aos amigos autores portugueses de Machado, que achei aqui: https://pontesdevista.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/machado-de-assis-e-os-portugueses/ que também cita outros clássicos (como Camões) que influenciaram o autor. Mais uma fonte nesse sentido é esse vídeo de um membro da ABL: http://ensina.rtp.pt/artigo/a-ligacao-de-machado-de-assis-a-literatura-portuguesa/ .

Comment: Há informações interessantes e bem contextualizadas sobre o posicionamento de Machado na polêmica criação da identidade linguística brasileira nessa tese: https://tede2.pucsp.br/bitstream/handle/14257/1/Agnaldo%20Sergio%20de%20Martino.pdf , mas como não achei nada específico sobre o tema da OP, não incluí o link na postagem. @Jacinto

Answer (score -1):

Este "estar + a" é uma evolução da forma do gerúndio que ocorreu em meados do século XIX em Lisboa e se espalhou para o norte do país. No Alentejo e no Algarve continou-se a usar o gerúndio. E obviamente no Brasil que já era independente e está muito distante de Portugal. Gerúndio é a forma original e que vem do latim.

Comment: terias alguma referência? Algo que possa "dar base" a essa resposta?

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Como diz o @Peixoto, é importante apoiar a resposta em fontes fiáveis. Há uma gramática de 1831 (posso encontrar se estiveres interessado) que já regista o *estar a* + infinitivo como equivalente ao gerúndio. E quão significativo foi esse uso no Brasil? É esse o cerne da minha pergunta. Por coincidência, ando a ler a "Saga" do Erico Veríssimo, e ele usa o *estar a* + infinitivo mais frequentemente que o gerúndio.

Comment: Eu ia falar que Machado de Assis e outros autores de outrora escreveram muito mais como o Português de Portugal atual como o Português do Brasil atual.