# É correto a construção ''estar + a + infinitivo'' em PT-BR

Tags: gramática, diferenças-transatlânticas

Tendo em vista a gramática do português do Brasil, a frase

> ''Estou a ficar cansado.''

está gramaticalmente correta? Eu tenho uma vaga lembrança de uma professora minha falando que isso é errado em PT-BR, mas certo em PT-EU. Procurei na internet, mas não encontrei tal informação.

Alguém saberia me responder?

Comment: A resposta a tua questão pode ser encontrada em perguntas já formuladas:  https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/o-s%c3%a9culo-est%c3%a1-a-expirar-estar-a-infinitivo-no-brasil?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.3481   e https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/874/porque-%c3%a9-que-em-ptpt-n%c3%a3o-se-usa-o-ger%c3%bandio Porque é que em ptPT não se usa o gerúndio?

Comment: Desculpe, mas acho que a resposta da minha pergunta não está em tais links. Minha pergunta é se tal frase está gramaticalmente correta em PT-BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa construção não é usada no português do Brasil. Ao invés dela, usamos o gerúndio para indicar uma ação em curso. No caso do seu exemplo, se diria "Estou ficando cansado".

Comment: minha pergunta é se a frase está certa ou errada em PT-BR. Nao tenho interesse em saber o que é o mais comum no Brasil.

Comment: É perfeitamente gramatical @MatheusManzatto  , e esse tipo de construção é até mesmo usada por algumas pessoas em nosso país.

Comment: @centaurus , obrigado pela sua resposta. Voce tem alguma referência? Você consegue me dizer porque está correto?

Comment: @MatheusManzatto   Está correto porque não fere nenhuma regra gramatical e é idiomático (muito mais em Portugal do que no Brasil, embora eu mesmo possa ocasionalmente dizer algo do tipo "vocês estão a brincar com uma coisa séria".)