# Qual é a origem da palavra gerúndio?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Os portugueses realmente fazem ou não fazem uso do gerúndio?.
E onde surgiu e qual o primeiro país a adotar?.

Comment: Na segunda pergunta, perguntas sobre a origem do gerúndio no português ou mais geral? Desculpa, não consegui entender direito.

Comment: Jhon, bem-vindo ao site. Parece-me que fazes duas perguntas muito diferentes. No corpo da pergunta, é sobre a origem do uso do gerúndio e se os portugueses o usam. Basicamente já tens reposta a isso [nesta outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/874/porque-%C3%A9-que-em-ptpt-n%C3%A3o-se-usa-o-ger%C3%BAndio) (até ao século XIX usava-se basicamente do mesmo modo no Brasil e em Portugal; depois a construção *estar/andar* + <gerúndio> foi caindo em desuso em Portugal). O que a outra pergunta e respostas não abordam explicitamente, é os primeiros exemplos conhecidos de uso >>

Comment: >> a origem mesmo (presumivelmente, vem da origem da língua). Se as respostas à outra pergunta já respondem às tuas dúvidas, deves fechar a tua pergunta como duplicada. Caso contrário, deverias editar a tua pergunta, mencionando a outra pergunta, e focando as coisas que gostarias de saber que não encontras lá respondidas. Depois, no título perguntas qual a origem da palavra *gerúndio*. Isto é uma pergunta diferente. Dado o corpo da tua pergunta, o título deveria ser "Qual a origem do (uso do) gerúndio"? Sobre a palavra propriamente dita, >>

Comment: >> podias abrir uma pergunta diferente ou simplesmente acrescentar, de passagem, no corpo desta pergunta (é uma coisa muito simples; encontra-se a resposta na maioria dos dicionários).

Comment: Jhon, já tens um voto negativo, que não é meu. Eu acho que uma pergunta sobre os primeiros exemplos conhecidos do uso do gerúndio é uma pergunta válida e possível de responder. Mas se quiseres ir por aí, deverias editar a pergunta para focar explicitamente isso e resolver a diferença entre título e corpo da pergunta.