# Qual a pronúncia que se assemelha mais com o Português falado há séculos? Do Brasil ou de Portugal?

Tags: origem-histórica, pronúncia

Qual a pronúncia que se assemelha mais com o Português falado há séculos? 4 Séculos atrás, Ex.

A pronúncia do Brasil, a de Portugal, ou outra?

Comment: Você se refere à pronuncia ou sotaque ? (pronunciation or accent?) falado há séculos onde ? Em Portugal ou nas colonias ? Quantos séculos atrás ? Falado há 10 séculos em Portugal ? Talvez ainda nem fosse língua portuguesa, mas sim o galego-português. Falado há 3 ´seculos no Brasil ? Sua pergunta precisa ser mais específica e mostrar o que você encontrou a respeito.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provavelmente uma do Brasil.

Nenhum lugar manteve a pronúncia (ou gramática, ou vocabulário) exatamente como era há séculos; e não é trivial julgar quais diferenças seriam mais ou menos significativas, para que se possa declarar que esse ou aquele dialeto é o que teria sofrido menor alteração.

Mas, baseado no que encontrei, eu diria que algum dos dialetos brasileiros provavelmente é o mais próximo do falar antigo português - [talvez](https://super.abril.com.br/cultura/sotaques-do-brasil/) algum mato-grossense ou nordestino.

Por exemplo, o jornalista e editor Denis Burgierman [escreve](https://super.abril.com.br/historia/falamos-a-lingua-de-cabral/):

> nós, brasileiros, mantivemos os sons que viraram arcaísmos empoeirados para os portugueses.

e dá um exemplo interessante:

> Luís de Camões (1524-1580) foi o maior poeta da língua. Mesmo assim, o escritor luso Antônio Feliciano de Castilho (1800-1875) achava seus versos péssimos. Há motivo para tal implicância. Um verso de Camões como “e se vires que pode merecer-te”, que para um poeta brasileiro é um decassílabo perfeito – frase de dez sílabas poéticas –, soa mal no ouvido de escritor luso moderno. “Os portugueses comem as vogais que precedem a sílaba tônica, a mais forte da palavra”, explica o gramático Evanildo Bechara, da Universidade Estadual do Rio de Janeiro. Assim, o verso vira “e se v’res que pode m’recer-te”. Fica com só oito sílabas, estragando a métrica.

Uma [matéria](https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/2015/04/08/ora-pois-uma-lingua-bem-brasileira/) da Revista Pesquisa FAPESP detalha:

> “Conservamos o ritmo da fala, enquanto os europeus começaram a falar mais rápido a partir do século XVIII”, observa Ataliba Castilho, professor emérito da USP, que, nos últimos 40 anos, planejou e coordenou vários projetos de pesquisa sobre o português falado e a história do português do Brasil.

É verdade que o português brasileiro contou com a influência considerável de outras línguas europeias e, especialmente, de línguas africanas e indígenas, mas isso se passou de maneira muito heterogênea (o 'r' caipira se concentra ao longo dos caminhos dos tropeiros, a influência do italiano e do alemão se faz sentir mais no sul do país, etc.), e mesmo a influência do português europeu não ocorreu de forma pontual - por exemplo, o 's' chiado, tido como tipicamente carioca, [teria chegado](https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/2015/04/08/ora-pois-uma-lingua-bem-brasileira/), [junto com](https://super.abril.com.br/cultura/sotaques-do-brasil/) o 'r' gutural afrancesado, com a corte portuguesa ao Brasil no início do século 19.

Mas, aparentemente, todas essas influências se somaram à língua, sem que isso fizesse sua componente portuguesa ter pressa em se alterar.

O linguista Ataliba Castilho (USP) [sumariza](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sDuGRKwguY):

> com o desenvolvimento da pesquisa, se verificou que nós estamos muito mais continuando o português [...] do século XV. [...] Não seria o português brasileiro que estava se afastando do português europeu, mas o contrário. Em algum momento o português europeu se afastou do ritmo que ele vinha tomando [...] enquanto que o português brasileiro deu continuidade, claro que com algumas alterações, àquele vocabulário, àquela gramática recebidos quando começou a colonização portuguesa aqui no Brasil.

Outro exemplo concreto, além do ritmo da fala, inclui o infinitivo gerundivo ("está a andar" ao invés de "está andando"), que começou a ganhar popularidade em Portugal [apenas no final do século XIX](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/875/2764).

Ainda sobre o ritmo de fala, vale citar diretamente uma [fonte acadêmica](https://doi.org/10.1590/S0102-44501998000200005) (via [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/696/2764)):

> Os historiadores da língua portuguesa concordam em afirmar que a pronúncia do PB é mais próxima da do Português Clássico (doravante PCl) do que a do PE. Este sofreu, com efeito, possivelmente na segunda metade do séc.18 (cf: Révah, 1958; Teyssier, 1980), uma mudança fonológica que está na origem da pronúncia moderna: a chamada redução das sílabas pretônicas.

Comment: Também já me tinha ocorrido que a poesia clássica portuguesa precisa de um sotaque como o brasileiro para respeitar a métrica "oficial". Mas "vires" nunca passa a "v'res", passa é a *virs* -- ter-te-ás enganado? -- a vogal tónica nunca desaparece. O verso pode na verdade passar a *e svirsc pod mrecer-te*, 5 sílabas, ou *mrcer-te*.

Comment: @Jacinto Boa observação, "virs" parece mesmo fazer mais sentido, mas o engano é da fonte original. Também vi referências (e.g., no vídeo que linko) ao encurtamento das palavras faladas ainda estar avançando em pt-PT.

Comment: Muito bom trabalho de pesquisa e muito interessante esse aspecto da métrica.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

Ide fazer uma visita ao norte-centro de Portugal e vereis se o "vires que pode merecer-te" não fica logo com as sílabas todas.
Além de que ler um poema em decassílabos com o mesmo passo fonético coloquial... Nunca seria boa ideia em terra alguma. Parece-me um bocado óbvio que quando lemos um poema, ainda para mais dessa natureza, o passo de leituras declamativa não deve ser igual ao passo da linguagem diária, sob pena de se perder quer a "música" quer até por vezes a sua inteligibilidade.
Isso não me parece um problema fonético do português europeu, isso parece-me um problema particular de quem lê. Não se lê um poema em decassílabos como quem conversa.

Comment: Não se lê um poema em decassílabos como quem conversa? Se fores o [Virtutis Discipulus](https://www.youtube.com/@VirtutisDiscipulus), se calhar lês... :D